# How to add single quote instead of double quote with raw query laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

Below is my query;

```
select "column1", "desc", if r_id = P then Y else 
'N' endif As is_selected from "other" where 
"rtype" = D_STATUS
```

Below is my query builder function,

```
DB::table('other')
->select('r_id', 'description', DB::raw("if r_id ='P' then 'Y' else 'N' endif As is_selected")) //Error
->where('rtype', '=',  $strType )
->get();
```

Here I got error ;

> Column "Y" not found.

I want to add single quote instead of double quote in all static string values in query. How can I do that?

Comment: Yes I just have to add single quote around column Y and N. Can you tell me how can I do this? @KamleshPaul

Comment: No backtick key is not working @KamleshPaul

Comment: i think you code is correct as error saying `Column "Y" not found` means in table this column is not present

Comment: NO my query is working fine. this query just missing single quote around 'Y' @KamleshPaul

Answer (score 1):

try it [this way](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_if.asp):

```
DB::table('other')
->select('r_id', 'description', DB::raw("if (r_id ='P','Y','N') as is_selected")) 
->where('rtype', '=',  $strType )
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use backlash.

```
DB::table('other')
->select('r_id', 'description', DB::raw("if r_id ='P' then \"Y\" else \"N\" endif As is_selected")) //Error
->where('rtype', '=',  $strType )
->get();
```

[here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) is the docs